# How to track user's emails and run script

Tags: php, email

I have 1 client who needs auto response script in PHP but not just in form even if he gets direct email on his inbox then the script should work.

I'm just confused that is it possible in PHP or not if its possible then how can we track his emails ?

Comment: sounds like something that should be set up on mail server

Comment: yes but client wants script only

Comment: what does "script only" mean in this context?

Comment: I mean he wants to set dynamic messages from his admin panel and when he receve new email in his inbox then 1 mail should send to sender with that content

Comment: "admin panel" ? sorry this is getting impossible to even guess at -and S.O is an *English* forum

Comment: its not duplicate check his title and my title both are different :D :P

Comment: @MohitBumb The titles are different, but the objective is the same. "if he gets direct email on his inbox then the script should work." That is exactly what is addressed by the question linked by Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = '';
$password = '';

function getUnreadMail($host, $login, $passwd) {
    $result = array();
    $mbox = imap_open($host, $login, $passwd);
    $emailIds = imap_search($mbox,'UNSEEN');
    foreach ($emailIds as $id) {
        $header = imap_headerinfo($mbox, $id);
        $email = $header->from[0]->mailbox .'@'.$header->from[0]->host;
        $result[] = $email;
        sendEmail($mbox, $email, $login, $cc="", $bcc="");
    }
    return $result;
}

function sendEmail ($mbox, $to, $return_path, $cc="", $bcc="") {
    $subject = "Test Email";
    $body = "This is only a test.";
    $headers = "From: ".$return_path."\r\n".
               "Reply-To: ".$return_path."\r\n";
    $a = imap_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, $cc, $bcc, $return_path);
    imap_append($mbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail",
     "From: ".$return_path."\r\n".
     "To: ".$to."\r\n".
     "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n".
     "Date: ".date("r", strtotime("now"))."\r\n".
     "\r\n".
     $body.
     "\r\n"
     );
    echo "Message saved to Send folder!<br />";
}

$count = getUnreadMail($hostname, $username, $password);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($count);
```